# Prove impossibility of expanding quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Consider the following setting: we have 4 points $p_1, p_2, q_1, q_2 \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and a function $f \colon \{p_1, p_2, q_1, q_2\} \to \mathbb{R}^k$, where $k < d$. All we know is that $(1-\epsilon) \lVert p - q \rVert \leq \lVert f(p) - f(q) \rVert \leq (1+\epsilon) \lVert p - q \rVert$ for some fixed $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ and all $p,q \in \{p_1, p_2, q_1, q_2\}$.

Assume that the segments $\overline{p_1 p_2}$ and $\overline{q_1 q_2}$, respectively $\overline{f(p_1) f(p_2)}$ and $\overline{f(q_1)f(q_2)}$, do not intersect.

Clearly, $p_1, p_2, q_1$ and $q_2$ form a quadrilateral (named $Q_1$) with diagonals $\overline{p_1q_2}$ and $\overline{q_1 p_2}$ and also $f(p_1), f(p_2), f(q_1)$ and $f(q_2)$ form a quadrilateral (named $Q_2$) with diagonals $\overline{f(p_1)f(q_2)}$ and $\overline{f(q_1)f(p_2)}$.

Now, I want to prove that it can not happen, that the following hold at the same time:

- $\lVert f(p_1) - f(p_2) \rVert = (1-\epsilon) \lVert p_1 - p_2 \rVert$,
- $\lVert f(q_1) - f(q_2) \rVert = (1-\epsilon) \lVert q_1 - q_2 \rVert$,
- $\lVert f(p_1) - f(q_2) \rVert = (1+\epsilon) \lVert p_1 - q_2 \rVert$,
- $\lVert f(p_2) - f(q_1) \rVert = (1+\epsilon) \lVert p_2 - q_1 \rVert$,
- $\lVert f(p_1) - f(q_1) \rVert = (1+\epsilon) \lVert p_1 - q_1 \rVert$ and
- $\lVert f(p_2) - f(q_2) \rVert = (1+\epsilon) \lVert p_2 - q_2 \rVert$.

I am not completely certain that this is the case, but my intuition is that this can not happen. So far, I tried to prove that the sum of the interior angles of the quadrilateral $Q_2$ would exceed $2 \pi$ in this case, but failed. (I tried to do this algebraically by using the law of cosines.)

If anyone could provide a hint for a working approach I would be very grateful.

Cheers!